# Wild classification problems and Borel reducibility

Tags: linear-algebra, lo.logic, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets, classification

My question is whether the archetype of 'wild' problems in algebra, namely classifying pairs of square matrices up to similarity, is 'non-smooth' in the sense of Borel reducibility.

This was implicitly raised by Joel David Hamkins in [his answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/10494) to the question [When is a classification problem "wild"?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10481/when-is-a-classification-problem-wild), but I'd like to make it explicit here.   Let me explain.

Wikipedia rather loosely defines a classification problem in algebra to be [wild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_problem) if it "contains" the problem of classifying pairs of square matrices up to similarity: that is, classifying equivalence classes of pairs $A,B \colon \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ where $(A,B) \sim (A',B')$ iff $A' = gAg^{-1}$ and $B' = gBg^{-1}$ for some invertible $g \colon \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$.  The looseness lies in the word "contains" and also how to deal with the fact that $n$ is a variable.  I hope it's been made precise somewhere but I haven't seen it done.

Meanwhile, there's an extensive theory of Borel reducibility that could serve to make this word "contains" more precise.

Briefly, a **standard Borel space** is a set $X$ equipped with a sigma-algebra of subsets that are the Borel sets for some separable complete metric on $X$; I'll call these **Borel subsets** of $X$.  A function between standard Borel spaces is **Borel** if the inverse image of any Borel subset is a Borel subset.    A **Borel equivalence relation** on a standard Borel space is an equivalence relation on $X$ that's a Borel subset of $X \times X$.   Getting to the point, we say a Borel equivalence relation $R \subseteq X \times X$ is **Borel reducible** to a Borel equivalence relation $S \subseteq Y \times Y$ if there's a Borel function $f \colon X \to Y$ such that

$$  x R y \iff f(x) S f(y) $$

Finally, we say a Borel equivalence relation is **smooth** if it's Borel reducible to the relation of equality on $\mathbb{R}$.

'Tractable' classification problems tend to involve classifying things up to some smooth equivalence relation, while 'intractable' problems tend to be nonsmooth.   For a good overview see:

- Greg Hjorth, Borel equivalence relations, *Handbook of Set Theory*, eds. Matthew Foreman and Akihiro Kanamori, 2009, pp. 297-332.

For a shorter intro see  [Joel David Hamkins' answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/10494).

So, we may ask if the problem of classifying pairs of square matrices up to similarity is non-smooth.   To formalize this, I guess we should form a Borel space of triples $(n,A,B)$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $A,B \colon \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ are linear maps: there is a straightforward way to do this.  Then we can form a Borel equivalence relation where $(n,A,B) \sim (n',A',B')$ iff $n = n'$, $A' = gAg^{-1}$ and $B' = gBg^{-1}$ for some invertible $g \colon \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$.   Then we can ask if this equivalence relation is non-smooth.  That's my question!

As a bit of tantalizing evidence, in Hjorth's article, when he's listing examples of smooth equivalence relations, he writes:

> Another example is the equivalence relation of matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ considered up to similarity. As remarked in [29], this equivalence relation is smooth, since we can assign to a matrix its canonical Jordan form as a complete invariant.

However, I don't see him coming out and saying the equivalence relation for *pairs* of matrices is non-smooth.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but for a fixed $n$ your relation looks like the product of two smooth relations (by Hjorth's comment), which is smooth as witnessed by the product of the two reductions to identity. Varying $n$ is a disjoint union of countably many smooth things, which is again smooth

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti this is not the product of the relations because the conjugating matrix has to be the same for both matrices.

Comment: I don't vote very much about these kinds of things. It is known that the first order theory of vector spaces over a fixed field K with two endomorphisms (viewed as part of the language) is undecidable.  Does this say anything about smoothness?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Borel complexity subsumes arithmetic complexity and far more---it is Delta^1_1---and so there aren't generally results along the lines you suggest. This is a step up from computability. Practitioners identify the Borel realm with "explicit" mathematics.

Comment: I associate the name of Mike Prest with logic and wild classification problems.  You might ask him

Comment: Ah that's a good point, I didn't notice you want the same $g$. So to show nonsmoothness we are looking for a Borel way to associate to every $x\in 2^\Bbb N$ a triple $f(x)=(n,A,B)$ such that $f(x)\sim f(y)\iff$ the two sequences agree on a tail. Maybe there is some clever construction where the length of the segment on which $x,y$ agree determines $n$?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti If the equivalence relation in the question is nonsmooth then it must be nonsmooth when restricted to some fixed $n$. So I don't think the role of $n$ should matter much as long as it is large enough.

Comment: Yes, given Borel relations $R_n$ on a countable collection of standard Borel spaces $X_n$ their disjoint union is a Borel relation on the disjoint union of the $X_n$.  So I could equivalently have asked whether for all $n$ the similarity relation on pairs of $n\times n$ complex matrices is smooth.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe surprisingly, the classification appears to be smooth.  I need to combine two results neither of which I understand, which is predictably fraught with danger, but here goes. The following appears as Proposition 2.1.12 in Zimmer's [*Ergodic Theory and Semisimple Groups*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4684-9488-4):

> **Proposition 1:** Suppose a locally compact second countable (Hausdorff, I assume) group $G$ acts continuously on a separable metrizable space $X$. If every $G$-orbit is locally closed, then the action is smooth (in the Borel sense).

Zimmer uses a different definition of smoothness but since I found this book referenced by a [paper of Kechris](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2000-13-04/S0894-0347-00-00341-6/S0894-0347-00-00341-6.pdf) using your definition of smoothness I will blithely assume that they are equivalent. Now we need a second result I don't understand:

> **Proposition 2:** An algebraic action of an algebraic group on a variety over $\mathbb{C}$ has locally closed orbits (in the Zariski topology, hence in the Euclidean topology).

This is supposed to follow from Chevalley's theorem.

> **Corollary:** For every $n$, the action of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ on $M_n(\mathbb{C})^2$ by simultaneous conjugacy is smooth (in the Borel sense).

Interestingly enough the result over $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't immediately follow because Chevalley's theorem doesn't hold. There's an [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181154/locally-closed-orbits-in-real-algebraic-geometry) about locally closed orbits for algebraic actions over $\mathbb{R}$ but I don't understand that one either. And of course I may have misunderstood the statements or the hypotheses of one or the other of these results...

(Also, as a comment, you can find a precise definition of wildness in [*Wild Hypersurfaces*](https://leuschke.org/uploads/Research/SU-wildhyps.pdf) by Leuschke, in the context of stating Drozd's trichotomy theorem.)

**Edit:** It would be interesting to more explicitly write down a Borel invariant which separates orbits here. The only invariants I can see are the following: given a word $w$ in the free monoid the Jordan normal form of $w(A, B)$ is a conjugacy invariant of the pair $(A, B)$. Based on [the answers to this old MO question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108783/are-two-elements-of-a-group-determined-up-to-simultaneous-conjugacy-by-the-conju) these are likely not to be complete conjugacy invariants, but I can't think of any others, personally.

Comment: For the real action, orbits are also locally closed (they are quantifier-free definable with polynomial inequalities).